# Why does a trait requiring AddAssign as a supertrait also require it to be Sized?

Tags: rust, traits, type-bounds

I have a trait, and to implement that trait, I would like to require the implementor to implement `AddAssign`; however, doing that results in *my* trait seemingly needing to require `Sized`:

```
trait Foo: ::std::ops::AddAssign {}

trait Bar: Iterator {}
```

<sup>[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b73ac30bd92ef6dfe226df309c1a1846&version=stable&mode=debug)</sup>

`Bar` compiles fine; `Foo`, however:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | trait Foo: ::std::ops::AddAssign {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Self` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Self`
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: std::marker::Sized` bound
  = note: required by `std::ops::AddAssign`
```

If I add `+ Sized` to the trait bounds, all is fine, but… why do *I* need to do this? Why doesn't `AddAssign` need this?

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the definition of the trait:

```
pub trait AddAssign<Rhs = Self> {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Rhs);
}
```

That is, `trait Foo: ::std::ops::AddAssign` is equivalent to `trait Foo: ::std::ops::AddAssign<Foo>` and `add_assign` takes a `Rhs` as its second parameter, hence `Rhs` needs to be sized.

Note that `trait Foo: ::std::ops::AddAssign<u32>` does not require `Foo` to be sized.

Comment: To put it in simple words, because operator `+=` takes the second operator by value, and by-value arguments must be sized.

Comment: Sure, that part I think I get; but why does `Sized` not otherwise also need to be mentioned on `AddAssign` / why is `AddAssign` not required to say `trait AddAssign<…> : Sized`?

Comment: The `Sized` requirements only comes from the fact that `Rhs` is used as a method parameter, and there it's implied because parameters always need to be sized.

Comment: @Thanatos: You could try implementing `::std::ops::AddAssign<&Foo>`, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: I understand that method parameters have to be `Sized`; but the `AddAssign` trait doesn't need to specify this. (As you say, "there it is implied") Why, when I use it as a supertrait, is `Sized` no longer implied?